# Cannot import completely CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I used this code to import my CSV file to table:

```
def Hotel.import(file)
  allowed_attributes = ["id", "name", "area", "short_name", "zip", "address", "tel", "fax", "staff_name", "information", "created_at", "updated_at"]
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.select{ |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
    product.save!
  end
end

def import
  Hotel.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Product Imported."
end
```

However, this code only insert id, created_at, and updated_at field to table. The insert command show here:

```
INSERT INTO `hotels` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-04-10 07:50:23', '2014-04-10 07:50:23')
```

I'm using rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0 to do this project. I check carefully to find error but I cannot find any problems here, so please tell me where I was wrong?

Comment: I can't find any errors. What does `row.to_hash.select{ |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }` return?

Comment: Are the allowed_attributes actually allowed within your strong parameters?

Comment: @Stefan the original code is '*accessible_atributes' instead of row.to_hash.select{ |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }, however this original code cause error in rails 4, then I searched and find this solution. This code is the thing that make me confuesed.

Comment: okay, but what does it return, could you show its output, i.e the hash it is returning?

Comment: insert `p row.to_hash.select{ |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }`, [`Kernel#p`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) inspects the object and prints the result, you should see it in your log

Comment: The expected output is the table with various columns like this:["id", "name", "area", "short_name", "zip", "address", "tel", "fax", "staff_name", "information", "created_at", "updated_at"]

Comment: The line I've posted (`p row.to_hash...`) should print a hash, something like `{"id" => "1", ...}`

Comment: Rails 4 uses Strong Parameters. Make sure you `permit` these parameters before mass assigning them. More info on Strong Params: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: @ermenkoff the OP is assigning a raw hash, strong parameters only work for [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) instances like `params`

Comment: @Stefan, good point. Then it should be an empty hash, as you implied, or mismatch of attribute names and csv column header names.

Comment: @Stefan did you mean this line `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"4r/9gQOS6ibhxcxwl7GF8TmOGYEXktcOaUGUS84sqmE=", "id"=>"126"}`

Comment: @hoamaudon no, that are request parameters. Call `Hotel.import` in `rails console`

Comment: @Stefan the console throw the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `import' for Hotel(no database connection):Class`

Comment: Maybe you're adding the `import` method from within your controller? Define it in your `Hotel` class, i.e. in the `hotel.rb` file, so it will be available anywhere.

Comment: @Stefan the message appeared: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Comment: Well, you have to pass a `file` to the method, right?

Comment: yeap!file is expected by import

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is that: when I exported file to Desktop then I chose open it by LibreOffice Calc(Ubuntu 13.10), so it was wrong format. I changed by opening by gedit text editor and it worked correctly. Very stupid error!